# Expression: Vector subscript out of range. Error 3 when using abort in console

Tags: c++, game-development, windows-11

I am unsure of what the issue is since I had no issues with my project the last time, I was working on it. I woke up this morning went to test what I had so far, and I've been hit with the "Expression: Vector subscript out of range" in an error screen right before it closes with error 3 when I click the abort button. It's a simple console RPG using C++ and I'm not sure what my vector is doing. It's involved in saving and loading characters to play the game with.

Game.h:

```
 #pragma once
#include "Functions.h"
#include "Event.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Game
{
public: 
    Game();
    virtual ~Game();

    //Operators

    //Functions
    void mainMenu();
    void InitGame();
    void createNewCharacter();
    void saveCharacter();
    void loadCharacter();
    void Travel();

    //Accessors
    inline bool getPlaying() const { return this->playing; }

    //Modifiers

private:
    int start;
    bool playing;

    //Character related
    int activeCharacter;
    string fileName;
    vector<Character> character;

};
```

And these are the functions involved with the vector. in my Game.cpp

```
 void Game::createNewCharacter() {
    string name;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "enter name for new character: ";
    getline(cin, name);

    character.push_back(Character());
    activeCharacter = character.size() - 1;
    character[activeCharacter].Init(name);
}

void Game::saveCharacter() {
    ofstream outFile(fileName);

    if (outFile.is_open()) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < character.size(); i++) {
            outFile << character[i].getAsString() << "\n";
        }
    }
    outFile.close();
}

void Game::loadCharacter() {
    ifstream inFile(fileName);

    this->character.clear();

    string name = "";
    int gold = 0;
    int distanceTrav = 0;
    int level = 0;
    int exp = 0;
    int Str = 0;
    int Con = 0;
    int Dex = 0;
    int hp = 0;
    int movespeed = 0;
    int statPoints = 0;

    string line = "";
    stringstream ss;

    if (inFile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(inFile, line)) {
            ss.str(line);
            ss >> name;
            ss >> gold;
            ss >> distanceTrav;
            ss >> level;
            ss >> exp;
            ss >> Str;
            ss >> Con;
            ss >> Dex;
            ss >> hp;
            ss >> movespeed;
            ss >> statPoints;

            Character temp(name, gold, distanceTrav, level, Str, Con, Dex, hp, movespeed, statPoints);

            this->character.push_back(Character(temp));

            cout << "Character " << name << " loaded!\n";
        }
    }
    inFile.close();

    if (this->character.size() <= 0) {
        throw "Error! No Characters Loaded or Empty File";
    }
}

void Game::Travel() {
    this->character[activeCharacter].travel();

    Event ev;
    ev.createEvent(this->character[activeCharacter]);
}
```

And this is my main:

```
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

   //int level = 12;
   //int i = static_cast<int>((280 / 3) * ((pow(level, 3) - 6 * pow(level, 2)) + 17 * level - 12));
   // cout << i << endl;

    Game game;
    game.InitGame();

    Inventory inv;
    //inv.addItem(Item());
    //inv.debugPrint();

    while (game.getPlaying()) {
        game.mainMenu();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In InitGame all I do is say welcome to the game, and the mainMenu is a case function that doesn't even get called before the error hits. If you need any more info, I will gladly provide it, I'm struggling with this probably obvious error for hours now.

Comment: What is your editing environment? Whenever you see anything that says "out of range," look at the call stack leading up to the error in your debugger of choice. Visual Studio provides a decent one built in that would be beneficial for you to learn.

Comment: I am actually using visual studios, and I'm not sure if this makes a different but I'm on windows 11 so I am using windows 11 sdk. Leading up to the vector subscript out of range it it says program: VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector Line:1463

Answer (score 0):

In game.cpp you have

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < character.size(); i++) {
            outFile << character[i].getAsString() << "\n";
        }
```

shouldn't it be the activeCharacter var you created earlier.

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < activeCharacter; i++) {
            outFile << character[i].getAsString() << "\n";
        }
```

say character vector has 10 elements, character.size() will return to so character[10] would be the supposed 11th element(out of bounds) since its supposed to be zero indexed (hence the activeCharacter = character.size() - 1) you declared earlier.

Comment: activeCharacter is the index in the save file of which line is which character. So if I put activeCharacter there it would always start program at 0. I did attempt that solution nonetheless and adding the -1 to character size again but no luck. Thanks for the idea though!